# How to create course in html and then export to Moodle

Tags: html, moodle

I am completely new to this. I want convert PDF files into HTML format and then i have to create interactive online course application that can be downloadable by students via Internet. Is any way to do it or how can i export this html content to Moodle.
I really struck with this........

Answer (score 0):

Most PDF files are somewhat graphics rather than editable documents. It is in this reason that you cannot directly convert them to HTML or moodle. If your PDF file has the text selectable, you might want to just copy the text and paste it into word or directly to moodle.

Comment: Thanks Jude, Is there any way to export my HTML website into Moodle